# Magento 1.9.3 International Phone prefixes

Tags: magento-1.9, php, jquery

Hello I would like to get help on adding the country code as prefix (+44, +234, +233 etc) in magento. I am currently using  1.9.3.2 version.Thanks

Comment: Can you specify some more detail about this? what you are looking?

Comment: Am looking at have to pre-fill the prefix with country flag and just enter the rest . for instance +234-8xxxxxxxx, +234 being Nigeria

Answer (score 0):

You can use Zend Validation for the phone number .
For example , in your controller :
Add a variable for validator :

```
$validator = new Zend_Validate_StringLength(array('min' => 8, 'max' => 15));
...

     $phoneNumber = $params['phone'];

...
```

//do some checks in your if

```
     if( .. !Zend_Validate::is($phoneNumber, 'Digits')
         || !$validator->isValid($params['phone'])
         ...

     ) { // Do something 
}
```

Not sure for the flag to display , but this can be a good start for you to check into ;) , with some debug from your part i think you can achieve what you want.